# making 3 different actions based on 3 different results

Tags: javascript

so i have this

```js
client.on("chat", async (channel, userstate, message, self) => {
  console.log(`Received message: ${message} from user ${userstate.username}`);
  if (self) return;
  if (userstate.username === "funtoon") {
    const catchRegex = /!catch (.*)/;
    const match = message.match(catchRegex);
    if (match && match[1]) {
      const response = await axios.get(
        "https://grynsoft.com/spos-app/?c=Vod_Kanakas&u=Vod_Kanakas"
      );
      const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

      const textRegex = new RegExp(
        `<b style="color: yellow;">${match[1]}<\/b>`
      );
      const textMatch = $("html").html().match(textRegex);
      if (textMatch) {
        console.log("Both style and match[1] are present");
      } else if (match[1]) {
        console.log("Only match[1] present");
      } else {
        console.log("Neither was present");
      }
    }
  }
});
```

expected results are

1. if `match[1]` and style are present in the same element do nothing
2. if only `match[1]` is present in the element `Only match[1] present`
3. if neither `match[1]` nor style are present 'Neither was present"

test results are

1. Both style and `match[1]` are present, doing nothing
2. Only `match[1]` present
3. Only `match[1]` present

i dont want to perform random releases if i dont have them to begin with. how do i make it so 3 works right without breaking the others?

tried using chatgpt but to fix this but nothing i gave me worked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd changed the last `if/elses` statement to :

```
   [...]
            const textMatch = $('html').html().match(textRegex);
            if (textMatch && textMatch[0].includes(`style="color: yellow;"`)) {
                console.log("Both style and match[1] are present");
            } else if (textMatch) {
                console.log("Only match[1] present")
            } else {
                console.log("Neither was present")
            }
   [...]
});
```

Comment: this comes back as 1) `Both style and match[1] are present` 2&3) `Neither was present`